# Existence of two normal vector fields with derivatives lying in $TM$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-forms, orthogonality, vector-fields

Given a 1-codimensional manifold $M^n\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and any local normal vector field $\nu$ it's straightforward to prove that $\partial_j\nu\in TM$, simply by differentiating the relation $\nu\cdot\nu=1$. In higher codimension, say $M^n\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$, this is not always true (it's enough to consider Frenet equations for a curve in the space).
I was wondering if it is always possible to construct a basis for $TM^\perp$ with this property, that is, such that
$$
\partial_j\nu_k\in TM\quad\forall j=1,\dots,n \text{ and }k=1,2.
$$

I made the following attempt. In a local chart for $M$ let $e_{1},\dots,e_{k}$ be a local orthonormal basis for $TM$ and $\nu_{1},\nu_{2}$ be an oriented orthonormal basis for $TM^{\perp}$. First, notice that differentiating the relations $\nu_{k}\cdot\nu_{k}=1$ we obtain $$\partial_{i}\nu_{k}\cdot\nu_{k}=0$$ so that in general we can write $$\partial_{i}\nu_{1}=\alpha_{i}^{k}e_{k}+\beta_{i}^{1}\nu_{2}$$
$$\partial_{i}\nu_{2} =\gamma_{i}^{k}e_{k}+\beta_{i}^{2}\nu_{1}$$
Moreover, differentiating $\nu_{1}\cdot\nu_{2}=0$ we find $$0=\partial_{i}\left(\nu_{1}\cdot\nu_{2}\right)=\partial_{i}\nu_{1}\cdot\nu_{2}+\nu_{1}\cdot\partial_{i}\nu_{2}=\beta_{i}^{1}+\beta_{i}^{2}$$so that $\beta_{i}^{1}=-\beta_{i}^{2}=:\beta_{i}$ and we rewrite $$\partial_{i}\nu_{1} =\alpha_{i}^{k}e_{k}+\beta_{i}\nu_{2}$$
$$\partial_{i}\nu_{2} =\gamma_{i}^{k}e_{k}-\beta_{i}\nu_{1}.$$
In general any oriented orthonormal basis for $TM^{\perp}$ can be written as a $SO(2)$-transformation of $\{\nu_{1},\nu_{2}\}$, so we set $$\mu_{1} =\cos\theta\nu_{1}-\sin\theta\nu_{2}$$
$$\mu_{2} =\sin\theta\nu_{1}+\cos\theta\nu_{2}$$ with $\theta$ being a smooth function defined locally on $M$. We compute
\begin{align}
\partial_{i}\mu_{1} &=-\sin\theta\partial_{i}\theta\nu_{1}+\cos\theta\partial_{i}\nu_{1}-\cos\theta\partial_{i}\theta\nu_{2}-\sin\theta\partial_{i}\nu_{2}
 \\&\in TM-\left(\partial_{i}\theta-\beta_{i}\right)\sin\theta\nu_{1}-\left(\partial_{i}\theta-\beta_{i}\right)\cos\theta\nu_{2}
\partial_{i}\mu_{2} \\&=\cos\theta\partial_{i}\theta\nu_{1}+\sin\theta\partial_{i}\nu_{1}-\sin\theta\partial_{i}\theta\nu_{2}+\cos\theta\partial_{i}\nu_{2}
 \\&\in TM+\left(\partial_{i}\theta-\beta_{i}\right)\cos\theta\nu_{1}-\left(\partial_{i}\theta-\beta_{i}\right)\sin\theta\nu_{2}
\end{align}
So we get to the result if we find a function $\theta$ such that $d\theta=\beta$, where $\beta=\beta_{i}dx^{i}$. By Poincaré lemma, such $\theta$ exists if $\beta$ is a closed form, so the claim becomes $$\partial_{i}\beta_{j}=\partial_{j}\beta_{i}\quad\forall i,j=1,\dots,n.$$
Now, to prove this I used that $\beta_i=\partial_i\nu_1\cdot\nu_2$ and hence
$$
\partial_j\beta_i=\partial_{ji}\nu_1\cdot\nu_2+\partial_i\nu_1\cdot\partial_j\nu_2
$$
Similarly
$$
\partial_i\beta_j=\partial_{ij}\nu_1\cdot\nu_2+\partial_j\nu_1\cdot\partial_i\nu_2
$$
Taking the difference we find
$$
\partial_{j}\beta_{i}-\partial_{i}\beta_{j}=\partial_i\nu_1\cdot\partial_j\nu_2-\partial_j\nu_1\cdot\partial_i\nu_2.
$$
From here I'm stuck. I tried several times applying different orthogonality conditions but I can't show that the r.h.s. is $0$. I suspect there may be some relation between $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ that I'm missing.
I'm interested especially in the case where $M$ is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Also, could the minimality of $M$ be of any help here?

Any hint is very appreciated.

Comment: In the case of curves, have you read about the Bishop frame? What you want is a parallel frame for the normal bundle.

Comment: A further comment: This is the analogue of the standard Riemannian result that zero curvature implies locally isometric to $\Bbb R^n$. You want a frame field for the normal bundle with zero connection forms, and so certainly you will need the curvature of the normal bundle to vanish, so it will need to have Euler class $0$ (in the codimension $2$ case). Minimality is governing only the trace part here. At any rate, basic topology should give the obstruction; if we take a surface $M\subset\Bbb R^4$ with nontrivial tangent bundle, then its normal bundle will have nonzero Euler characteristic.