# Block metric tensor and Fermi coordinates.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, tensors, tensor-decomposition

Consider a manifold $M^2\subset\mathbb{R}^4$ locally parametrized by $Y(\xi^1,\xi^2)$ and let $X$ be a Fermi coordinates parametrization of a neighbourhood of $M$ (which we call $\bar{M}$), that is
$$
X(\xi^1,\xi^2,z^1,z^2)=Y(\xi^1,\xi^2)+z^1\nu_1(\xi^1,\xi^2)+z^2\nu_2(\xi^1,\xi^2)
$$
where $\nu_1,\nu_2$ are two orthonormal fields. In the codimension 1 case it's fairly easy to see that the metric tensor for $\bar{M}$ is given by
$$
g_{\bar{M}}=\begin{bmatrix}g_{M_{z}} & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $M_z=M+z_1\nu_1+z_2\nu_2$. In codimension 2 I expect the same block decomposition for the metric tensor
$$
g_{\bar{M}}=\begin{bmatrix}g_{M_{z}} & 0\\
0 & I_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but I can't prove it through rough calculations. In short, the problem is given by the fact that, in general
$$
\partial_j\nu_1\cdot\nu_2=-\partial_j\nu_2\cdot\nu_1\ne0
$$
and this nonzero term gives a nonzero element on the anti-diagonal blocks. Hence, this block decomposition actually depends on the choice of $\nu_1,\nu_2$ somehow.

Here [Existence of two normal vector fields with derivatives lying in $TM$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3964846/existence-of-two-normal-vector-fields-with-derivatives-lying-in-tm) is described how I tried to "rotate" the basis for $TM^\perp$ to obtain another one with $
\partial_j\nu_1\cdot\nu_2=-\partial_j\nu_2\cdot\nu_1=0
$ but this didn't yield to any conclusion. Is there any quicker way to ensure the existence of the block decomposition?

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: You're having trouble proving it, because it's not possible in general. If there are coordinates $(x^1,x^2,t^1,t^2)$ such that the metric is $g_{ij}dx^i\,dx^j + (dt^1)^2 + (dt^2)^2$, then the level sets $\{ x^1 = a\text{ and }x^2= b\}$ are flat. But it's not possible in general to foliate a Riemannian manifold by flat surfaces.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I’m not familiar with the concept of foliation of a manifold, is there any hypothesis I can add to make this always possible?

Comment: I don't know. But one way to start is to study the consequences of such coordinates, especially for the curvature tensor. Once you understand this, you can try to figure out whether the converse holds or what additional assumptions would be needed for it to hold.